# Hover effect not being applied to SVG Nested in NavLink

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, react-router

**How do I get the nested SVG to have the same hover effect as the anchor tag? When I hover over one it should change both, but right now they are not being seen as the same entity.**

I am trying to apply a style to an SVG on hover. The SVG is nested inside of a NavLink component. The CSS that is class-specific gets applied to the SVG, but the hover for the a tag that the SVG is nested in only applies to the a tag's text. I have tried using just the Link component from react-router-dom. I have noticed that when I removed the `text-decoration: none` from my CSS, the underline only applies to the text. In the rendered HTML the a tag DOES nest the svg tag.

I have tried wrapping the anchor tag and SVG in a span and giving the span the hover effect, it did not work.

component

```
import {Link, NavLink} from "react-router-dom";
import logo from '../../assets/LogoOnly_Square_Transparent.png';
import { ReactComponent as CalculatorIcon } from '../../assets/calculator.svg';
import './header.styles.scss';

export const Header = () => {

    return (
        <nav className="header">
            <div className='options'>
                <Link className='logo-container' to='/'>
                    <img src={logo} alt="Logo" className='logo'/>
                </Link>
                <NavLink to='/calculator' className='header-option'>CALCULATOR<CalculatorIcon className='link-icon'/></NavLink>
            </div>
            <div className='options-right'>
                <Link to='/sign-in-sign-up' className='header-option'>SIGN IN</Link>
            </div>

        </nav>
    )

}
```

CSS

```
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D1D3D4;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 5px;

  .options {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;

    .logo-container {
      width: 70px;
      margin: 5px 0;
      height: 100%;
      .logo {
        height: 100%;
      }
    }
      .header-option {
        padding: 10px 15px;
        font-size: 16px;

        .link-icon {
          height: 13px;
          fill: #58595B;
          margin: auto 5px;
        }
        &:hover {
          color: #4FB47C;
          fill: #4FB47C;
        }

      }
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #58595B;

    &:hover {
      color: #4FB47C;
      fill: #4FB47C;
    }
  }
  .options-right {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;

    .header-option {
      padding: 10px 15px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with your question - there is no question.

Comment: I guess the question is, how do I get the hover effect to work on the nested SVG?

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the question added as a comment. Many do not read the comments.